# Textarea displays \n character instead of displaying endline properly

Tags: javascript, textarea

I am creating a project where I need to update a textarea field with info from mysql database.

If i manually put in the javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myTextArea').value='Line1\nLine2';
```

the textbox displays it properly.

In my script, at some point I update the value with a string received from an ajax request:

```
document.getElementById('myTextArea').value=result.slice(18);
console.log(result.slice(18));
```

In this case, the text area displays the text like this:

> This should be the first line.\nThis should be the second line.\n.And so on...

At the console log I get properly the text:

> This should be the first line.\nThis should be the second line.\n.And so on...

But I want it displayed in the textbox with endlines.

Below is a picture containig the sql table, the console output and the way textarea displays the text:

!http://s22.postimg.org/npzonvm9d/textarea.png

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I see that you are using phpMyAdmin to store the value inside the database. The string is probably escaped, so the string is not really "\n", but "\\n". Easiest (and ugliest) solution would be: `document.getElementById('myTextArea').value=result.slice.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was in comments.

The string is probably escaped, so the string is not really "\n", but "\n". Easiest (and ugliest) solution would be:

```
document.getElementById('myTextArea').value=result.slice.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
```

I would suggest doing this server side

```
$result = str_replace('\\n', '\n', $stringfromdb);
```